# ListBox or Combobox ADODB imported Decimal items invisible in the list

Tags: sql, vba, excel, combobox

I have encountered this problem several times already and have been able to work around it till now. Also the almighty search engines didn't help me.

The problem is that when I have populated a listbox or combobox from a ADODB recordset all Decimal data elements are not visible in the box, for example with the following (conn is a ADODB connection):

```
Private Sub GetFilteredRecords()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim arr As Variant

    'create the SQL
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM vwStandard_Fee2"

    'execute the SQL and fill the rs ( rsFiltered )
    Set rsFiltered = conn.Execute(strSQL)

    'Apply recordset to the listbox on the form
    If Not (rsFiltered.EOF = True And rsFiltered.BOF = True) Then
        arr = rsFiltered.GetRows()
        With lbDeeper
            .ColumnCount = rsFiltered.Fields.Count
            .List = TransposeArray(arr)
        End With
        With cbDeeper
            .ColumnCount = rsFiltered.Fields.Count
            .List = TransposeArray(arr)
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Above contains 6 columns of Ids (all show Type = Variant/Decimal), of which the containing values are all not "shown" for some strange reason. Only the String and Date columns are shown normally, the Decimals are there but empty!

Here some snippets:

[image: General layout of arr]

[image: String is shown, decimal is not shown]

[image: See that EUR is shown and the decimal field next to it isnt!]

Now in case of a combo box I can get one column's value shown if their column the BoundColumn when I select that listitem, but only in the value fo the combobox (so still not in the list).

My initial workaround was to convert them into String values before adding to the Listbox/Combobox, in this case however I want to directly link the query result to the Box.List without looking at the details. And thus I am looking for a solution in stead of a work around.

In short: my numerical field items are invisible BY DEFAULT for some strange reason. Workaround was to make the items String values. I am now looking for a solution for this bug/problem instead:

1. What is causing this?
2. How to solve it?

Comment: What's you ColumnWidths property look like?

Comment: Have you done .visible=false somewhere else on the controls? Can you update your question with how does your combo and list boxes look like with invisible data?

Comment: COlumnWidths isnt set (thus all columns are equally wide, which I have verified by setting the ColumnHeads = True). The Box is visible, I have just tried with another .Visible=True to see if that matters, but alas. Also dates just as texts are shown without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after going through various possible causes it seems to be the case that:

VBA has no Decimal Variant Type of its own.
VBA can handle Decimal from within a variable declared as Variant (thus becoming a Variant/Decimal)
This normally doesn't stop your program from working, but in Controls like Listbox and Combobox the Type Variant/Decimal is not interpretable and thus wont draw that specific entry.

For example populate a listbox called lbHigher with this:

```
Private Sub ListBoxProblem()

    Dim tempArray(2, 2) As Variant

    tempArray(0, 0) = "A"
    tempArray(0, 1) = 1
    tempArray(0, 2) = 1.1
    tempArray(1, 0) = "B"
    tempArray(1, 1) = CStr(CDec(5.2))
    tempArray(1, 2) = 2.3
    tempArray(2, 0) = "C"
    tempArray(2, 1) = DateSerial(2012, 12, 13)
    tempArray(2, 2) = 100
    tempArray(3, 0) = "D"
    tempArray(3, 1) = -1
    tempArray(3, 2) = CDec(5.2)

    lbHigher.ColumnCount = 3
    lbHigher.List = tempArray
End Sub
```

Everything works fine except for the CDec(5.2). The CStr(CDec(5.2)) works fine as well as VBA will first have converted the Decimal to String before the Listbox gets to get it.

So either: Dont let the SQL generate any Decimal output OR convert any Decimal output to Single/Double/String/Integer/Long in VBA before handing it to the Listbox.

Comment: Conversion to String was the first solution in my answer and back in square one! ;)

Comment: Agreed, and I am grateful for your help, it did however not answer my primary question: **What is causing this?** Which is also not found with various searches on the internet...

Comment: BTW this is interesting, but I am surprised these errors still persists if that's what nearly causing your disaster. [listbox, combox decimal conversion bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/accessdev/thread/01d1da4d-4294-44f3-976a-2aa771fa4a03) Usually we do convert data to string before displaying in these controls. Specially if you happend to use C# sort of platform. OR else it's populated on sql statment via rowsource property. Not involving an array.

Comment: indeed, such error/bug/glitch in the software for so long. It amazes me, thanks for the good links there as well...

Answer (score 1):

So all string data is appearing? And,only numerics don't appear?

Then you may want to convert your numerics to strings and pass it to your list, combo boxes.
Which you have already done I noticed.

Now for any reason if your max number of rows and length of array/recorders row count doesn't match it could also cause an issue. However it seems your setting rows of combobox using recordset row count. Instead of using an array can you try to iterate over the recordset to populate the combobox? yes this is not performance friendly, buy guess what we need it to work without bugs before optimizing. ;-)

Have you bound your combobox to the recordset? Can you confirm if your array is single dimension and it has data to feed to the box?

You may try to populate the listbox using a saved query in the DB to if the issue still persists. 
*However, list boxes and combo boxes based on SQL statements are slower than
 list boxes and combo boxes based on saved queries.*

So can you try the following to set `rowsource` property? Make sure to test on both number,and test columns. As well as on old combo box and new one.

```
Rowsource->build query->
sqlview copy to rowsource property box-> 
delete or don't save that above built query since you already have SQL statement.
```

Just wanted you to try out possibilities to narrow down the issue.

---

**UPDATING ANSWER WITH MOST POSSIBLE ISSUE AND SOLUTIONS**

As per my comments, they mainly given assuming you had issues populating listbox/combobox

> I forgot to ask something very very important, have you declared
>   Option Base 1 to make sure to avoid losing one of the array's column
>   values if you are dumping 2D array...? because you do not have any
>   explicit declartion for the array you are using to dump data into the
>   listbox.......... :)

Make sure your **Listbox is enabled to show multi column data.**

**So you have three choices, **

- Option Base 1
- ReDim your array and do looping to fill it and dump it into .list.
- Since ReDim array need you to anyway loop through, you may just as well 
  use the recorset iself to add the data.

You seem to have a dimension issue with the array which is not declared but transposed from recordset and then to listbox/combobox. So your undeclared array is not populating multi-columns properly. That could be the reason it works when you declare array proeprly.......

Infact in your comment you have said so,

> When I create an array in my code and populate it in my code (entry by
>   entry) it will show without any problem – K_B 14 mins ago

Comment: The max number of rows matches, and it is populating fine apart from this "glitch". Iterating gives the same result, only slower as you mention. When I iterate indeed I can convert the numericals to String, however that still leaves me puzzled why this doesnt work properly.

Comment: I have added snippets to show how my array looks, its a 2 dimensional matrix, thus fits the lists, which it populates fine except for this. Using a saved query in the database doesn't change the outcome, numerical stay missing. I will try the rowsource now, however I never used that before as it looks a bit dodgy to me...

Comment: Just noticed how awful it looks when an answer is added from mobile. Geez. So how about the latter, the usual way of doing it with `rowsource` property bind to the `sql statment`? Didnt get a chance to try out, let me give it a shot in my side.

Comment: BTW if you are using `.List` property you do not have to worry if it's 1D or 2D array. Only when you add items like `.AddItem` you gotta specify the indices like `0,0`. I am smelling something here now.. get your array to be 1D just with the data you need and dump it to `.List` and see how it goes. I have a *bad mild feeling* it will work ;)

Comment: So for rowsource I have to have the SQL query result in a sheet? That feels messy to me as different people in this company have different decimal characters (comma or period) and different date formats (4 different) which I don't want to get clogged up into!

Comment: Nope, not at all. I mean to say, since you are dumping your array to the `.List` property directly, you can try that with a 1D array and see if it works. There's no need to involve Sheets here.

Comment: @K_B I forgot to ask something very very important, have you declared **`Option Base 1 `** to make sure to avoid losing one of the array's column values if you are dumping 2D array...? because you do not have any explicit declartion for the array you are using to dump data into the listbox.......... :)

Comment: option base is not declared and thus it is 0, which i find very convenient. For filling the List it is no problem as everything is there, the numerical entries are just not showing (they are in it, but just not shown)

Comment: So you have three choices, either use **1.** Option Base 1 **2.** ReDim your array and do looping to fill it and dump it into .list. **3.** since you are looping an array, just might as well use the recorset iself to add the data. Why do you have to use an array anyway.

Comment: When I create an array in my code and populate it in my code (entry by entry) it will show without any problem

Comment: It seems to be that all the entries that are Variant/Decimal arent shown. And decimal isnt a Type in Excel VBA...

Comment: What do you mean by this? "When I create an array in my code and populate it in my code (entry by entry) it will show without any problem" 1. Doesn't it mean you are declaring your array dimensions? 2. So that means you could use that method, isn't it? 3. OR ARE YOU saying, even after declaring an array and populating the listbox, you still have issue of not showing numbers? Clarify please.

Comment: What I am saying is that when I dont use a recordset but just do a couple of lines of arr(x,y) = <VALUE> all these <VALUE>'s are shown in the list, also numerical ones. The problem seems to be that recordset dataitems of the type Decimal cannot be handled properly by the List- and Comboboxes. Reason looks to be that Decimal is NOT a declarable Variant type in VBA...

Comment: it is NOT a dimension issue. You can see in my original code that the dimensioning is perfectly fine

Comment: Then query the recordset and populate the array or just use the recordset to pupulate the listbox. If decimal has an issue then convert that into integer/number.

Comment: I fear that is the only solution indeed as VBA (as the only language around?) doesnt have this Decimal type. Thanks for helping!